# Trouble getting MySQL data into BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to get my MySQL server's data into BigQuery.  So I believe I needed to set up a MySQL connection from GCP Data Fusion.  Here is my source node's properties (see screen shot):

[image]

The the mysql server is running and security group allows 3306 traffic and I can connect to the server from my laptop using the `mysql` client.  But when I attempt to "Browse Database" button (shown here):

[image]

But when I click on that button I see this screen:

[image]

and when I try to use the above page I get this error:

```
Failed to explore connection. Error: "Failed to create connection to database via connection string: 
jdbc:mysql://ec2-52-37-71-250.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3306:3306 
and arguments: {user=root, rewriteBatchedStatements=true, connectTimeout=20000, socketTimeout=20000}. 
Error: SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://ec2-52-37-71-250.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3306:3306."
```

The hostname use above `ec2-52-37-71-250.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com` is the old instance name.  How can I change `ec2-52-37-71-250.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com` to the restarted instance's hostname `ec2-35-166-99-251.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com`?

Comment: Could you follow this [document](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/tutorials/replicating-data/mysql-to-bigquery) to Replicate data from MySQL to BigQuery?

Comment: @PrajnaRaiT Thanks.  I will try that today.  Does my MySQL server have to be on GCP Compute Engine or can I substitute my on-prem MySQL server for it?

Comment: @PrajnaRaiT it would still be nice to know how to update my MySQL connection when I stop then start my EC2 instance.  Doing the stop & start causes the EC2 instance to change its IP and hostname.